# PHP_Calculator_Code

Tags: php

I have a project where I am going to create a calculator using PHP. I have done all the basic arithmet ic operation and it is operating well. My only problem is that, if the user for example had already entered numbers and he/she chose to add it, and after that, if the user would want again to enter another input, the previous answer should be erased and the newly entered input should have an empty space first. Here's our code:

Comment: We assume an error in submission? Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript - when any of the buttons are pressed, clear the input field.

If you MUST use PHP, just set the input's value to `value=''`, so when the page reloads, it's empty.